# Does $0\le A \le B \Rightarrow A^2 \le B^2$ hold?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

given two pos. semi-definite, symmetric matrices $A,B.$ Is it then true that if they satisfy $A \le B$ then $A^2 \le B^2$? I can neither find a proof nor could I find a counterexample in the internet, but I guess it is wrong. Can anybody here say more about this?

Edit: I define $A \ge B $ if and only if $\langle x,(A-B)x \rangle \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $n$ is also the size of the matrix.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance, but how are you **defining** $A \leq B$?

Comment: $A \le B$ if and only if $\langle x,(B-A)x \rangle \ge 0. $ for all $x$ in the vector space

Comment: @Henry yes, but that is really not the question here, sorry. ;-)

Comment: If $x$ takes values in $\mathbb{C}$, then what do you mean by $\ge 0$? If you restrict to reals, the question is answered by a rotation by $\pi/2$ and the identity matrix.

Comment: @ well $\ge 0$ means that the quantity $\langle x, (B-A)x \rangle $ is real and positive...

Comment: In your definition of positive semi-definite, are you also implying $A,B$ are symmetric?

Comment: @AlexR. well, I did not, but I added it, since it is a quite reasonable condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $B-A$ has eigenvalues $0,2$, whereas $B^2-A^2$ has a negative eigenvalue: $3-\sqrt{10}$.